# JS: Problems Accessing Data In Object From Within An Enclosed Function

Tags: javascript, function, javascript-objects

I want the refer to the stuff inside the object with the this-keyword.
I want all data to be in one object.
Now I ask myself how to access the data from within other functions.

I have no clue.

```js
    var composer = {
      currentChordType: [],

      setChordType: function() {
        this.currentChordType = [5, 4];
      },

      getNextChord: function() {
        var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
        switch (index) {
          case (0):
            {
              switch (this.currentChordType[0]) {
                /* more code .... */
              }
            }
            /* more code .... */
        }
      }
    }

    composer.setChordType();
    composer.getNextChord();
```

**Error** is: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`

the line that makes problems is: `switch (this.currentChordType[0]) {`

Comment: That code does not throw that error. You need to provide an [mcve] that actually demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Your code is working: https://jsfiddle.net/mrlew/kk3ozcnf/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am betting that your *real, actual, breaking code that you didn't provide to us* does something like `button.addEventListener("click", composer.getNextChord)` or something similar with a callback somewhere. In such a case you need to `bind` the method to the composer object.

After you define your composer, bind the methods to it:

```
var composer = {
   ...
   getNextChord: function() { ... }
};

// Add this bit:
composer.getNextChord = composer.getNextChord.bind(composer);
```

Comment: You are absolutely right. thank you. it wasn't obvious to me. but how does `.bind()` work?

Comment: As simply as I can put it, `.bind()` sets the context for whenever a function is called. Most of the time you don't need to use it. But whenever a function is passed as a callback, I'd say 7.3 times out of 10 you need to bind it to the right context so that when it's called, `this` is what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the scope is getting messed up inside the `switch` statement. Developers usually preserve scope by assigning `this` to another variable and then accessing it everywhere else. So try this

```
 getNextChord: function() {
    var that = this;
    var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
    switch (index) {
      case (0):
        {
          switch (that.currentChordType[0]) {
            /* more code .... */
          }
        }
        /* more code .... */
    }
  }
```